# Angularjs handling nested promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have below code in my application,

```
$scope.addZero = function(x,n) {
            while (x.toString().length < n) {
                x = "0" + x;
            }
            return x;
        }

    $scope.msToTime = function() {
            var d = new Date();         
            var h = $scope.addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
            var m = $scope.addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
            var s = $scope.addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
            var ms = $scope.addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
            return h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms;
        }

    var Deferred = $q.defer();
    Deferred.resolve('outer success');                
    var promise = Deferred.promise;
    promise
    .then(function () {
            var anotherDeferred = $q.defer();
            console.log("Main Start "+"TimeInSeconds >"+$scope.msToTime());
            $scope.StartTime = $scope.msToTime
            $scope.myCall = $interval(function() {
                anotherDeferred.resolve('inner success');                 
                var anotherpromise = anotherDeferred.promise;
                    anotherpromise
                        .then(function (data) { 
                                console.log("Inner Start "+"TimeInSeconds >"+$scope.msToTime());
                                return Myservice.db('mytable'); 
                              })
                        .then(function (data) {
                                console.log("Inner check 1 "); 
                                $scope.EndTime = $scope.msToTime
                            })
                        .catch(function error(errmsg) {
                                        console.error(errmsg);
                            })
                        .finally(function() {
                                console.log("finally "+"TimeInSeconds >"+$scope.msToTime());
                            });
            }, 1000,2); 
    return $scope.myCall;
        })
    .then(function() {
            console.log("Done");
        })
    .catch(function error(errmsg) {
            console.error(errmsg);
        })
    .finally(function() {
            console.log("Main finally "+"TimeInSeconds >"+$scope.msToTime());
        });
```

And referring $scope in html like this,

```
<div>{{StartTime()}}</div> </br> 
<div>{{EndTime()}}</div>
```

The problem is , things are not working in sequentially as expected. When i take console output , it is as below.

```
Main Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:09:686
Inner Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:10:687
finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:10:690
Inner Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:687
Done
Inner check 1
Main finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:687
finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:6879
```

I expect it to be like Main finally should come after inner loop is over. How can i handle nested promises in sequence. I added "return $scope.myCall;" to inner promise but that also waits only the first "then" and rest is ignored. 
Second, why StartTime gets changed every time when EndTime changes, it should be change only once when main starts ? please help.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise that is returned by `$interval`.

You've assigned `$scope.myCall` to the promise that `$interval` returns, but you don't return that to the outer promise. If you return that promise in the same block of code in which it is defined as follows:

```
.then(function () {

    $scope.myCall = $interval(function() {

    }, 1000,2); 

    return $scope.myCall; 
})
.then(function(){

})
.catch(function error(errmsg){

})
.finally(function(){

})
```

Then it should give you the desired result:

```
Main Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:09:686
Inner Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:10:687
finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:10:690
Inner Start TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:687
Done
Main finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:687
finally TimeInSeconds >10:52:11:687
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. It worked. But one doubt. why "finally TimeInSeconds" comes after "Main finally". I am asking just for knowledge. And what about the $scope.StartTime.

Comment: @sand in truth I'm not entirely sure. If anyone else could pass any comment that would be welcome and I'd learn something from this myself!

Comment: it didn't work actually. Because it takes only the first "then" function in sequence. If we add mode then functions to inner promise, those  executed after "Main finally"